# Sorting List on basis of certain letter

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort a list on basis of `C` before `.`

Is there better way to do this?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    List<String> activeLoadList = new LinkedList<String>();
    List<String> tempList = new LinkedList<String>();
    activeLoadList.add("REL1110C.PZ");
    activeLoadList.add("REL1110Z.PS");
    activeLoadList.add("REL1110C.AB");
    activeLoadList.add("REL1110Z.CD");
    activeLoadList.add("REL1110C.OP");

    System.out.println("Queue is ***" + activeLoadList);
    
    Iterator<String> iter = activeLoadList.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String next = iter.next();
        if (next.contains("C.")) {
            iter.remove();
            tempList.add(next);
        }
    }
    
    activeLoadList.addAll(tempList);
    System.out.println("Queue is ***" + activeLoadList);
  }
}
```

Output:

> Queue is ***[REL1110C.PZ, REL1110Z.PS, REL1110C.AB, REL1110Z.CD, REL1110C.OP]
>
> Queue is ***[REL1110Z.PS, REL1110Z.CD, REL1110C.PZ, REL1110C.AB, REL1110C.OP]

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. Do you want to maintain the intial order but the "C." at the end?

Comment: Yes, I want to sort term in order such that all term having `C.*` shall come in end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of modifying the structure of the list (adding, removing) you should rather use a `Comparator` (see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)), which in your case could look like this:

```
Collections.sort(activeLoadList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        boolean aContainsPattern = a.contains("C.");
        boolean bContainsPattern = b.contains("C.");
        if (aContainsPattern == bContainsPattern){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return aContainsPattern ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
});
```

Note though, that you could/should extract your pattern to a constant instead of having it duplicated (like in my example) and furthermore, that you could use a lambda instead of an anonymous inner class if you use Java 8.

**Edit:**

In case you use Java 8 (and the ternary operator `?`) you *could* boil that down quite a bit:

```
final String p = "C."; // the pattern to search for
Collections.sort(activeLoadList, (a, b) -> (a.contains(p) == b.contains(p) ? 0 : (a.contains(p) ? 1 : -1)));
```

But for the sake of readability you may rather use the more verbose version. Furthermore *Solomonoff's Secret*'s solution is to prefer in case you won't have any further sorting criteria in the future. If you may have additional ones, though, a `Comparator` may be the easier way to go.

**Edit 2:**

As has been pointed out by *Solomonoff's Secret* this could even be simplified further with Java 8's `Comparator.comparing`:

```
Collections.sort(activeLoadList, Comparator.comparing(text -> text.contains("C.")));
```

**Edit 3:**

Thanks to *Fabio F.* for an even short version using Java 8:

```
activeLoadList.sort(Comparator.comparing(text -> text.contains("C.")));
```

Comment: I believe your second example can be simplified using `Collections.sort(activeLoadList, Comparator.comparing(text -> text.startsWith("C.")))`, which would make your sorting much shorter than my answer. It would also IMO be much more readable than my answer.

Comment: I suppose that the condition expression `aContainsPattern && bContainsPattern` should be `aContainsPattern == bContainsPattern` – if I get the problem correctly, two items are equal when both have `"C."` substring or when neither has it.

Comment: In Java 8 List have sort method so you could just write:
`activeLoadList.sort(Comparator.comparing(text -> text.contains("C.")));`

Answer (score 4):

Philonous's answer solves this problem in `O(n * log(n))` time. This answer will solve it in `O(n)` time, albeit with a bit more code than in the other answer. Note that in this case performance might not matter; however, it could matter if you were to scale up to millions of items. This answer requires Java 8.

```
    final List<String> unsorted = ...
    final Predicate<String> startsWithCDot = str -> str.startsWith("C.");
    final List<String> sorted = Stream.concat(
        unsorted.stream().filter(startsWithCDot.negate()),
        unsorted.stream().filter(startsWithCDot)
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```